# How to create s3 bucket in aws using jmeter POST method

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, post, bucket, creation

I am trying to create a s3 bucket in JMeter using post method can someone send me the request body  and the path for creating a bucket.

Any links for more scenarios for testing s3 buckets.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AWS S3 REST api
[AWS S3 REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CreateBucket.html)

The examples are in cURL so you will need to craft your request. I am not sure if JMeter provides a way to import requests using cURL syntax.